# How to add a untracked local folder to remote Git repository?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a local folder `someFolder` that is not under Git, and I want to somehow "merge" this folder with the repository on a remote server `https://github.com/blah.git` on the master branch. In my master branch on the remote server i have a bunch of folders and i want my local folder to be added in the top level.

What's the Git way to do this?

So far, i cloned my remote git repository in to some other folder on my local machine. then, i manually moved my local folder `someFolder` to the top level of my locally checked out repository, and added/committed/pushed on that. I feel like there's got to be a more Git way to do this though. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I feel like there's got to be a more Git way to do this though. any ideas?

Not really, unless you start playing with `GIT_WORK_TREE`, which would allow you set the work tree to another directory (like the parent directory of your folder), **allowing you to avoid moving that folder in your local repo**:

```
 git clone https://github.com/blah.git 
 cd blah
 git --work-tree=/path/to/parent/folder add yourFolder
 git commit -m "add new folder"
 git push
```

From the [git man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git.html):

```
--work-tree=<path>
```

> Set the path to the working tree.
>   It can be an absolute path or a path relative to the current working directory.
>   This can also be controlled by setting the `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variable and the `core.worktree` configuration variable.

That can come in handy if you have to add regularly changes from that folder in your repo.
You can check for any changes (again without having to copy said folder in your local repo), with a:

```
     git --work-tree=/path/to/parent/folder status -- yourFolder
```

---

The [OP David.T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/770452/david-t) [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023529/how-to-add-a-untracked-local-folder-to-remote-git-repository/18023897#comment26673886_18023897) though:

```
git --git-dir=/Users/me/Desktop/testWorkTree/.git --work-tree=/Users/me/Desktop add someFolder
```

yields:

```
fatal: pathspec 'testWorkTree/someFolder' did not match any files
```

Comment: However, I think doing it that way may cause more problems than it solves, since the `--work-tree=...` that you specify is highly likely to be missing a whole bunch of stuff that `git` expects to find (i.e. the entire remainder of the project's work tree). I haven't actually messed with external work trees much, though, so I could be wrong...

Comment: @twalberg no it won't be an issue, since you are adding (or checking the status of) **`someFolder`, and *only* `someFolder`**. So I disagree: it will work just fine.

Comment: I tried to do this, but it's not allowing me to use the parent directory for some reason. under my `~/Desktop/` i have `testWorkTree/` and also `someFolder/` where `testWorkTree` is a directory under git. in that directory, if i try `git --work-tree=../ add someFolder` it gives me an error: `fatal: pathspec 'testWorkTree/someFolder' did not match any files` and if i do the absolutely path: `git --work-tree=/Users/me/Desktop/ add someFolder` then it still says `fatal: pathspec 'testWorkTree/someFolder' did not match any files`. putting quotes for file names don't help.

Comment: @DavidT. try and specify `git-dir` as well. You should be able to execute that command from any path: `git --git-dir=/Users/me/Desktop/testWorkTree/.git --work-tree=/Users/me/Desktop add someFolder`

Comment: it actually still doesn't work - i get the same errors, but i think this is sufficient enough of an answer so that i can explore more around bare base git repos and what work trees actually are, so i'll just accept and close out the question. thanks!

Comment: @DavidT. ok, I have included the error message in the answer. Let me know if you can make it work, and I will update this post accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I think your way is good enough. However, just to demonstrate the nature of git and how cool it is, I show another way - use standard `git merge` to *somehow "merge"*.

I assume you have `localFolder/someFolder`:

```
$ cd ..../localFolder
$ git init #yes, we just created a new git repo
$ git add someFolder # obviously, you may have any files and folders, not only one
$ git commit -m "We now have some added"
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/blah.git
$ git fetch
$ git merge origin/master # we are merging 'two repos'
$ git push -u origin master
```

Done. It looks nothing special - two repos are just the same as two mere branches.

Comment: +1 this answer pretty easy to understand. i've used merge before and i was kinda afraid that this would be the only other way to do things, it just seemed slightly manual as well :/ but oh well. thanks!